# Is there any public streaming api?

Tags: api, github, github-api

I have read the [github api docs](http://developer.github.com/v3/) and I haven't found any streaming api like [twitter streaming api](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis). 
I want to implement public github repository feed via js on client side without a server.
Is it possible?
Should I create a server and github app and authenticate my server on github so I can make all requests through it?

Answer (score 1):

There is no streaming API for GitHub. I doubt they have plans of adding one either to be frank.

Your initial request can get the last 30 events and then poll with the ETag header of that request for updates. You'll need to be authenticated (somehow, not necessary via an app) to make it work. Considering each request should come from a different IP address I would hazard a guess that the rate-limits wouldn't be applied globally to all visitors regardless of who they're authenticating as. That, however, would be an excellent question for the API support team at GitHub.

Comment: So I can't implement it client side without user authentication on github?

Comment: You don't need your site visitors to authenticate. You will just not want to do it through the unauthenticated API endpoints. If you do, your rate limit will be 60 requests per hour. If you authenticate though (even as yourself without making an app) you will get bumped to 5000 per hour so you can poll more frequently.